# How to create line data with start and end x,y coordinates that also follows a road network shapefile in QGIS

Tags: line

I am using QGIS.

I currently have a road network that some work is occurring on here and there and I need to produce line data that shows exactly where along the network the work is happening. I have an excel spreadsheet of all the lengths of road that requires work: start chainage, end chainage, total km, and x/y coordinates for start and finish. I also have a separate line file of the total road network.

Is there a way I can automatically create lines that start and finish at the x/y coordinates, follow the road, and somehow have the excel spreadsheet attached as attributes?

I have so far begun creating points from the x,y coordinates.  However, I am struggling to figure out how to join the two points AND have them follow the road alignment.

EDIT:
Please see below photos to assist with this question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to do routing in QGIS?

Comment: I want to result in having a shapefile with only the sections of road that require work - so there will be lines here and there, but not the entire network. Is there a routing function for this that can do every location all at once?

Comment: So I understand that you have a network of road and out of which few roads have some work to be done, like repair etc. In your excel you have lat, lon coordinates of start and end points. Do you know which roadId this start and end points belong to? May be a diagram would help clarify your question more.

Comment: I have added a photo to the main question. Unfortunately I do not have the roadId

Comment: If I understand what you need linear referencing would be the way to go : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_referencing. As you are using QGIS you will need the LRS plugin : https://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.0.3.7/index.html